# How to search phrases in a string in python

Tags: python, file

I change my text file into a string. The string has been formatted to look like

```
{'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}
```

I then used this code to try and find the number of times a name appears in the data. However, it returned the actual original string. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
searchfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in searchfile:
     if 'author name' in line: print (line)
searchfile.close()
```

What I would like is for it to print the 'author name'

Comment: I think you don't want a space between `file` and `.txt`

Comment: My file needs actually needs to have that or it wouldn't read it

Comment: @mbi How so? Usually there is know space in a path.

Comment: What does `file .txt` look like? What is your expected output?

Comment: file.txt is just a string of about 400 names with separated by brackets, commas, and quotations mark

Comment: Well that makes things a bit simpler

Comment: Please provide sample lines from the file, what you expect your output to be, and what the output actually is. As is, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Could you show the format of the names. Is it like `["anna", "gracie", "cade"]`?

Comment: I've edited to make it easier to understand

Comment: So you mean a dictionary?

Comment: Yes but the dictionary was in a list format originally

Comment: Got you. Let me see if i can come up with something

Comment: Thank- you, Mr.gooseberry

Comment: FYI. If talking to someone specifically we(SO people), usually say @person name.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchfile = open('test', 'r')
word = "test"
lst = []
for line in searchfile:
    a = line.split()
    for x in a:
        if x == word:
            lst.append(x)
print(lst)


searchfile.close()
```

This took a little bit of research and testing, but it should do what you wanted :). So the line.split() will essentially put words separated by space in the text file into a list. From there, you cycle through the list checking if it matches the world. If it does, it will push it into our list and later on print it so we can see.

If you were searching Smith for example it would be "'Smith," because there's no space separating the ' and , from Smith unless you want to make a function that removes the : , ' { }.

Comment: It actually returned lst=[]

Comment: You need to look at the string in your text file and change it appropriately to word = "test". For example, if it's 'Stevens,' the "test" would have to be "'Stevens,'"

Comment: Hmmm. It doesn't work with the way you formatted it. If it was formatted to be something like StevenP it would work 100%

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to count the number of times a particular name appears in your string, you can maintain a counter map against it. Something like

```
import sys

def main(some_name):
    counter_map = {}
    for x in input_string.split(','):
        if some_name in x:
            count = counter_map.get(some_name, 0)
            counter_map[some_name] = count + 1 
    print(counter_map[some_name])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

and the `input_string` looks something like below

```
input_string = """
{'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, {'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, 
{'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, {'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, 
{'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, {'AU': 'Smith, S’}, {'AU': 'James, A’}, {'AU': 'Stevens, P’}, {'AU': 'Smith, h’}, 
....
"""
```

Prints out the following on my end (used a larger file)

```
$ python counter.py Smith
576
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need, assuming that the whole file is a string as you said. It searches for the `name` argument given and if found prints that `name` argument. Otherwise it prints `"not found"`:

```
file = "{'AU': 'Smith, S'},{'AU': 'James, A'},{'AU': 'Stevens, P'},{'AU': 'James, A'}"


def find_name(name, nameString):
    curWord = ""
    if name in nameString:
        print(name)
        return
    else:
        print("not found")

find_name('James, A', file) # output:'James, A'
find_name('Jane, A', file) # output: 'not found'
```

**Note**. it only prints the name is finds one time. Your going to have to use a loop if you wanted name printed out as many times as it it found.

Comment: this would be printing out names as many times it appeared, the OP asked for getting the count.

Comment: @SaifAsif Actual it does not. It prints the name **one** time, no matter how many times it shows up. And it is really not clear what  the OP asked for. He first said: _I then used this code to try and find the number of times a name appears in the data_. But at the end he said: _What I would like is for it to print the 'author name'_. So it is not clear what he wants. I gave him what he asked for at the end of the question.